# What is the index [0] for on post meta fields?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

Trying to improve my PHP knowledge through test and try! I am confused on [0] arguments at following WordPress PHP code

```
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$price = $custom['price'][0];
$coMake = $custom['coMake'][0];

echo $custom['price'][0];
```

Are they for indexing/referencing inputs on the page? if so why they are same?! can you please let me know why and when to use them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each post meta key can have multiple values. So you get the values by default as an array; the first entry (`0`) is the oldest.

`get_post_custom()` fetches all meta keys with their values. You could simplify your code with:

```
$price  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price', TRUE );
$comake = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'coMake', TRUE );
```

When the last parameter for `get_post_meta()` is `TRUE`, WordPress will return a single value: the first entry in the post meta value for the given key.

The first call to `get_post_meta()` will fetch and cache **all** meta values for that post ID in the background, so later calls will not result in additional database queries.

#### An example

Let’s say, we create a post meta key named `color` and fill it with three different values for **one** post. Then we do the same with a key `age`.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {

    foreach ( array ( 'blue', 'red', 'yellow' ) as $color )
        add_post_meta( 561, 'color', $color, FALSE );

    foreach ( array ( '14', '40', '104' ) as $age )
        add_post_meta( 561, 'age', $age, FALSE );
});
```

The last parameter `FALSE` tells WordPress *not* to make this meta key *unique* – but to allow multiple values for one key instead.

The resulting structure in our `postmeta` table will look like this:

[image: table]

Each row has a unique `meta_id`, but each `post_id` can have multiple `meta_key`s, and each `meta_key` can have multiple `meta_value`s.

Now let’s fetch all custom values for post 561:

```
add_action( 'shutdown', function(){

    $custom = get_post_custom( 561 );
    print '<pre>' . esc_html( var_export( $custom, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
});
```

Result:

```
array (
  '_edit_last' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
  ),
  '_edit_lock' => 
  array (
    0 => '1367617428:1',
  ),
  'color' => 
  array (
    0 => 'blue',
    1 => 'red',
    2 => 'yellow',
  ),
  'age' => 
  array (
    0 => '14',
    1 => '40',
    2 => '104',
  ),
)
```

`_edit_last` and `_edit_lock` are WordPress internals, we ignore that for the moment. Just note, we get these values an an array too, although there is just one value.
`color` and `age` are arrays like all post meta values.
`$custom['color'][0]` is `blue`.

Now we fetch just the color with `get_post_meta()`:

```
add_action( 'shutdown', function(){

    $color = get_post_meta( 561, 'color' );
    print '<pre>' . esc_html( var_export( $color, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
});
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 'blue',
  1 => 'red',
  2 => 'yellow',
)
```

We get just one piece of our meta values here. `$color[0]` is still `blue`. Behind the scenes, WordPress has already fetched *all* custom values, so a next hit for `age` would be served from the cache.
In terms of performance `get_post_custom()` and `get_post_meta()` are equal.

Last attempt: Get the color with `get_post_meta()` as a single value.

```
add_action( 'shutdown', function(){

    $color = get_post_meta( 561, 'color', TRUE );
    print '<pre>' . esc_html( var_export( $color, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
});
```

Result: `blue`.

WordPress has done what you have done in your code: It has taken the array key `0` and returned the value as a string.

This is the most readable option, use it to write code that is easy to understand.