# Filter get_adjacent_post to follow woocommerce product category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How do I filter get_adjacent_post to follow the next category by the product category drag & drop screen? Is using get_categories correct? How do I join it into get_adjacent_post?

```
$post_prev = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
$post_next = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

$args = array(
    'parent'        => 0,
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat'
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`get_adjacent_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post/) function has multiple arguments. The fourth and last one is the `taxonomy`, which per default is `'category'`:

```
$post_prev = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'product_cat' );
$post_next = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false, 'product_cat' );
```

Comment: Side note: That function is extremely slow. See the [alternative implementation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101475/73) which is ten times faster.