# Using Custom Post Meta Values in Shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I'm trying to display meta content from a custom post type in a shortcode. I'd like to simply provide a post_id and be able to display all the meta content.

```
[my_shortcode post_id=""]
```

I'm new to PHP and writing shortcodes, this seems as though it should be fairly simple...  I know the following is wrong:

```
function promotion_function($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'promo_id' => '',
), $atts));
global $post;
$meta_values = get_post_custom($promo_id, 'product_desc');

$output = $meta_values;
return $output;
}
add_shortcode('promotion', 'promotion_function');
```

The above code gives me the string "Array" in my page.

I can't find an example of how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom doesn't take a key only a post ID. Access the value using a key on the resulting Array.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print an array directly. The most basic return value you could use is [`var_export( $meta_values, TRUE );`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

This will create a text representation of the value.

Probably better is a little walker like

```
$output = '';

foreach( $meta_values as $key => $value )
    $output .= "$key = " . esc_html( end( $value ) ) . '<br />';

return $output;
```

Comment: Ay, thank you. I had tried something similar with no luck.  This certainly helps.

Interesting; now I get an array for each key's value.  I was expecting one value.  I fear I may be asking some very basic questions... Is there a codex link I should be referencing for this?  I've already reviewed the get_post_meta codex page..  Thanks again.

Comment: @lauren See this explanation: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100699/73

Comment: You rock.  Thank you - I'll chew on that for a bit.

Comment: I'm still getting all of the keys displaying all of their values.  I thought using 'true' would only display the first value.  Here's my code:

    `function promotion_function($atts) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'promo_id' => '',
 ), $atts));
 
 $get_title = get_post_custom($promo_id, product_title', true);
 $title = esc_html( var_export( $get_title, TRUE ) );
 
 return $title;
    }
    add_shortcode('promotion', 'promotion_function');`

I apologise for my code block not being a code block; I'm finding the instructions for creating a code block in comments to be extremely unclear :/

Comment: @lauren The `TRUE` parameter work only on `get_post_meta()` like you need it, not on `get_post_custom()`. You need [`end()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php). I will update my answer in a minute.

Comment: I'm still pretty lost here.  I now get nothing when I use end().  I'm just trying to display one value from a custom post meta key in my shortcode.  I keep finding the same thing when I research on google : get_post_meta($promo_id, 'product_title', true) and that does nothing for me... No matter how I write it.  Not getting any php errors... :/

Comment: Alright, here is what worked:
$meta_values = get_post_custom($promo_id, 'product_title', true); echo $meta_values['product_title'][0];