# Can A Post Meta Field Store multiple values that are not in an array?

Tags: post-meta, array, sanitization

I have a post_meta field that seems to be displaying multiple values, yet they do not seem to be in an array.  Using debug bar, this is what I see inside of the '_custom_post_type_onomies_relationship' meta field.

[image: screenshot]

I want to filter these id's to return titles instead.  Because I am using Facet WP, I need the values to NOT be an array when done.

```
$item_array = get_post_meta( $post->id, '_custom_post_type_onomies_relationship' );
foreach ( $item_array as $item_id ) {
   $title = get_the_title( $item_id );
   $item_array[] = $title;
}

update_post_meta( $post->id, '_custom_post_type_onomies_relationship', $item_array );
```

This works just fine except that it is an array.  What data type is that custom field before I filter it?  How do I reproduce that data type?

Note: Before I filter it, the data type must not be an array because FacetWP can understand it.

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100696/what-is-the-index-0-for-on-post-meta-fields for an explanation of post meta storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta data keys do not have to be unique, you can have multiple rows of the same key, each containing singular values. If you use `get_post_meta` to fetch a key and don't set the 3rd argument to `true`, the function gets all the individual values and returns them as an array, which is not the same as getting a single value that is an array saved as a serialized string.

If you want to iterate over the returned array and save new values, you have to call [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) for each item in the array, and set the 4th argument of the function, which is the old value of the particular row you'd like to update.

```
$item_array = get_post_meta( $post->id, '_custom_post_type_onomies_relationship' );
foreach ( $item_array as $item_id ) {
   $title = get_the_title( $item_id );
   update_post_meta( $post->id, '_custom_post_type_onomies_relationship', $title, $item_id );
}
```

Comment: What would be a good hook to try this on?  save_post?