# get_post_meta / update_post_meta array

Tags: post-meta

I am trying to save the ID of the current user (if user is logged in) within an array in a post_meta key called "post_is_read" in every post the user reads so I can perform certain actions such as  label the post as "unread".

I added this in **single page** template:

```
$readers = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_is_read');
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if (!in_array($current_user->ID, $readers)) {
   $readers[] = $current_user->ID;
    update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_is_read', $readers, false);
}
```

Inside the posts loop I added the following code:

```
$readMeta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_is_read', true );
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $readMeta != $current_user->ID ) {
   echo 'unread post';
}
```

I tried many variations of the first block of code, altered add_post_meta, update_post_meta etc. One problem I recognized is when printing the array stored in the meta key "post_is_read" the output is just "array". I think this is a major problem if it is not the only one in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) in two different ways: the first, leaving `$single` unset (it defaults to `false`) will get you the full array of meta entries for the given key; the second, setting `$single` to `true`, will get only the *first* item with that key.

What you want, I believe, is an array of user IDs attached to each post in the `post_is_read` meta.

Here's how I'd attack the problem:

**single page template**

```
// Get the list of readers.
$readers = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_is_read', true );
// If the value is empty, make sure it's an array.
if ( empty( $readers ) ) {
    $readers = array();
}
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! in_array( $current_user->ID, $readers ) ) {
   // Adds the current user ID to the $readers array.
   $readers[] = $current_user->ID;
   // Updates the 'post_is_read' meta.
   update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_is_read', $readers );
}
```

**posts loop**

```
$readers = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_is_read', true );
if ( empty( $readers ) ) {
    $readers = array();
}
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! in_array( $current_user->ID, $readers ) ) {
   // If the current user hasn't read the post, make a note of it.
   echo 'unread post';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort put in offering a solution to my problem. I can't try the code at this moment but will do later and let you know. Leaving $single unset was on purpose as I read in wordpress codex it has to be false (as is by default) otherwise the meta_key accepts only one value and replaces it with the latest, if one provided.  Something else about $readers = array(); I had the impression, as I read on wordpress documentation that wordpress perceives $readers as an array by default so why declare it?

Comment: Also I do not get why $single is set to true since I am searching for the user's ID which will not necessarily be the first object in the array.
Edit: I read this answer (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245505/15801) which explains it but still can't get it...

Comment: Thank you very much, code tested and works like a charm! I really appreciate it!

Comment: A post can have multiple metadata set on it, using the same key. So setting `$single` to `true` tells WordPress that you want only the first entry to be returned. Leaving it `false` will return *all* the entries in an array. Since you want a list of users, it's better to set just one metadata entry, and save it as an array.

Comment: Also, if the answer works for you, please feel free to mark it as **Accepted**.