# meta_query check for meta value in key which holds an array of values

Tags: query-posts, meta-query, meta-value

In every post of my custom post type called `"announcements"` I save the users' ID inside an array which resides in a meta_key called `"post_is_read"` whenever a user reads an announcement.

Just to explain: "post_is_read" contains an array (1, 2, 5, 12, 86, 100) where every number represents a user ID.

I achieved this using this code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/344315/15801

I am now trying to create a template which will show the posts a user has not read with the following code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$up_an_query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'announcement',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'date', 
    'order'          => 'DSC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'post_is_read', 
            'value'   => $current_user->ID,
            'compare' => 'NOT IN',  
        )
    ),                                      
);
```

I have read every related article/answer I've found both on and off wordpress stackexchange and no method worked for me. The most I could get it to work is using  `'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'` but it messed up the posts being displayed for users having at least a common digit in their IDs (ex between 1, 10, 11... etc) which is something I understand why is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Revised Answer

<sup>( PS: I actually wanted to revise this answer long ago, but eventually I kept forgetting to do so. :) )</sup>

So in this revised answer, the main point is the first one below, but I hope the rest also help you:

1. What you're trying to do is not going to be (easily) possible with the way the IDs are stored, which is serialized such as `a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:10;i:2;i:11;}` (for `array( 1, 10, 11 )`).

   What if the current user ID is 10 and in the meta value, there's an `i:10;i:9`, i.e. array item keyed 10 with the value (a user ID) of 9 (i.e. `$some_variable[10] = 9`), but the ID 10 is not actually in the list?
2. So because of the above, you might better off create a custom database table and store the user ID and post ID in their own column.

   And if you want, you can check a simplified [example/demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wYErkyWw8WpArgNxwbU3o/2).
3. Or you could instead store each user ID in individual post meta named `post_is_read`. That way, filtering the posts would be easy — but the post meta table would end up being really huge with many, many rows...

   ```php
   // Saving the meta:
   add_post_meta( 1, 'post_is_read', 10 );
   add_post_meta( 1, 'post_is_read', 11 );

   // Then when filtering the posts:
   $user_id = 10;
   $args = array(
       'meta_key'     => 'post_is_read',
       'meta_value'   => $user_id,
       'meta_compare' => '!=',
   );
   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   ```
4. Or you may use a serialized value, but store the user *name/login* and not the ID:

   ```php
   // Store usernames and not IDs.
   $usernames = array( 'foo', 'user-bar', 'etc_etc' );

   update_post_meta( 123, 'post_is_read', $usernames );
   ```

   And then you can use the `NOT LIKE` comparison like so:

   ```php
   $username = 'user-bar';
   $args = array(
       'meta_key'     => 'post_is_read',
       'meta_value'   => '"' . $username . '"', // search for exactly "<username>" (including the quotes)
       'meta_compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
   );
   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   ```

### Original Answer

Please check the [revisions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/344929/revisions), but basically in my original answer, I was saying if you'd rather use the user IDs, then you could store them as a comma-separated list like `1,10,11` and then use the `NOT REGEXP` comparison:

```php
// Saving the meta:
update_post_meta( 1, 'post_is_read', '1,10,11' );

// Then when filtering the posts:
$user_id = 10;
$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'post_is_read',
    'meta_value'   => "(^|,)$user_id(,|$)",
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT REGEXP',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And that did (and still does) work (with WordPress 5.6.1), except that it needs an extra parsing when retrieving the meta value, e.g.:

```php
$ids = get_post_meta( 1, 'post_is_read', true );
$ids = wp_parse_id_list( $ids ); // convert to array
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sally. Isn't it better to save the meta as serialized like the way all the data are being saved in the database by WP itself? I mean, in a sense of having a solid, well preserved/structured database. Also what should I place in my single page (or how to alter the existing code) in order to read the value in the posts loop? Is it like `if ( ! in_array( $current_user->ID, $ids ) ) {` ? As for the "alternate" solution, it would be a bad practice as the website I am building will have way too many users (students) and DB would end up huge indeed.

Comment: WordPress serializes meta values which are array because the values have to be saved as string in the database. And I've already explained in my answer how a comma-separated list is better than a serialized string - at least in your case - but if you do not need to query the meta value using the `meta_query` (or `meta_value` and `meta_compare`) parameter(s), then the meta value can just be saved as a serialized string. And I didn't suggest using `NOT LIKE` because you've already tried it and you know it didn't work properly.. :)

Comment: And regarding using it (in The Loop, etc.), basically you just need this extra part which converts the list to an array: `$ids = wp_parse_id_list( $ids );` - after that, you can use `in_array( $user_id, $ids )` to check if a certain user ID is within the list.

Comment: Thank you very much Sally, will try your solution and let you know. I am just curious, would your method work the same way if I was storing words instead of IDs? I suppose I should use `wp_parse_list` instead. Is `wp_parse_id_list` used solely for IDs or works for any number regardless? I am sorry to bother you but I am more interested in learning how things work instead of just coping/pasting some code.

Comment: (Re-posted) Yes, my method would also work for arrays of words like `[ 'word', 'word2', 'etc' ]` - but each word shouldn't have a comma (`,`) *or* space. And if you intend to store usernames, then you'd use `wp_parse_slug_list()` which works for slug-alike strings (e.g. if one's name is `John Doe`, then the slug would be `john-doe`). And `wp_parse_id_list()` works for any (comma- or space- separated) list which contains just numbers regardless the numbers are actual IDs or not.

Comment: I just tested the code. It saves and reads correctly however I had to set a default meta value for `post_is_read` when saving a new announcement in order for the query to work (worked normally with `REGEXP` but not with `NOT REGEXP`. While it seemed to be working at first, it messed up the posts being displayed for users having at least a common digit in their IDs (ex between 1, 10, 11... etc). Same results as the previous code gave me.

Comment: I've just [updated](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/344929/revisions) the answer. Let me know.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much! I didn't include the "relation" though, I like the idea of setting a default meta value (0 in my case) better.

Comment: Hi @ArgGeo, how are you? I've just revised my answer (I made it more generalized) and I hope it's still acceptable to you. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

I store my IDs as strings so this is what I do

```
$up_an_query_args = array(
'post_type'      => 'announcement',
'post_status'    => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby'        => 'date', 
'order'          => 'DSC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'post_is_read', 
        'value'   => serialize(strval($current_user->ID)),
        'compare' => 'LIKE',  
    )
),);
```

The same should work even if you store it as int:

```
'value'   => serialize($current_user->ID)
```

Comment: Thank you, man. that works perfectly.